# C++11 bound method signature simplification

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void f(T t1, T t2) { std::cout << t1 << " " << t2 << std::endl; }

template<typename...Ts>
void g(Ts... ts) { f(ts...); }

int main() {
    auto f = std::bind(g<int, int>, 1, 2);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to skip the template type specification for `g` in `std::bind(g<int, int>, 1, 2)` ?

If not, is it at least possible to specify the type just once? i.e. `std::bind(g<int>, 1, 2)`

Here is a [live version](https://ideone.com/ZYanNU) of this.

Comment: It doesn't change that much, but you can use `std::bind(static_cast<void(*)(int, int)>(g), 1, 2);`. Template types specification is gone actually. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible with bind, but you get same functionality with a lambda, and no need for explicit template params:

```
auto f = []{
    g(1, 2);
};
```

Comment: Of course. I was insisting on getting bind right but I do not especially need it. A lambda works great. Thanks!